Как открыть ссылку в отдельном браузере из Telegram Mini-Apps
Я сделал игру на юнити, портировал её в телеграм, и столкнулся с проблемой: когда я хочу открыть ссылку (например в ютуб) используя Application.OpenURL, то ссылка открывается внутри телеграма, хотя мне нужно в отдельном браузере. Также я сделал вот так:
<script src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-web-app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openInNewTab(url) {
      window.Telegram.WebApp.openLink(url);
    };
</script>

в html коде и
Application.ExternalCall("openInNewTab", "https://www.youtube.com");

в C# скрипте игры, как итог все тоже самое.
Как обойти WebView от телеги, чтобы ссылка открывалась и с андроида и с iOS?
